# How can I create fixed position table footer?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React and Material UI framework.

How can I make the last row of a table fixed in position? On the bottom of the page, this row will always be visible.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-o4hb6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) where I tried that, but for some reason, the table cells won't align correctly. It seems that the property `display: contents` controls this behavior, but using position fixed contradicts it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Material UI Table now comes with the `TableFooter` Component. So just copy the `TableHead > TableCell` and only change the CSS `top:0` to `bottom:0`. Or you can override `MuiTableCell` like so:

```
export default createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiTableCell: {
            footer: {
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0, // <-- KEY
                zIndex: 2,
                position: 'sticky'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Also set the `TableBody` `margin-bottom` to match the footer height.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the 'sticky-footer' table cell data inside a new `table` element to keep the correct formatting.

Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { TableFooter } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  table: {},
  stickyFooter: {
    bottom: 0,
    position: "fixed",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
  }
});

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

export default function SimpleTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper>
      <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
          </TableRow>
          <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table, classes.stickyFooter} aria-label="simple table">
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
          </Table>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It seems to work only if the content of the cell is exactly the same as the header. Otherwise, it won't keep the width correctly.

Comment: Yeah, because once you set the position to sticky it doesn't have a reference to the original chart, so you will have to complete it with some custom styling

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, but my temporary solution was to use nested grids and give each grid component the prop component="table"/"td"/"tr" ..